# While I'm trying to add new migration, I get this exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, database-migration, app-config

While I'm trying to add new migration, I get this exception.

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception.

This is App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, Z.EntityFramework.Classic, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=afs71658f100c290" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
<connectionStrings configSource="bin\ConnectionStrings.config" /> 
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, Z.EntityFramework.Classic.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

And this is ConnectionStrings.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Finance" connectionString="data source=192.168.0.6;initial catalog=Finance_Test;user id=sa;password=$Finance@92" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And this is stack trace:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unable to open configSource file 'bin\ConnectionStrings.config'. (C:\MyProjects\Finance\Shoniz.Finance.Persistence\tmp2747.tmp line 8)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_ConnectionStrings()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..ctor()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForAssembly(Assembly assemblyHint, Type contextTypeHint)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForContext(Type contextType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1..ctor()
   at Shoniz.Finance.Persistence.Migrations.Configuration..ctor() in C:\MyProjects\Finance\Shoniz.Finance.Persistence\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 10
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.MigrationsConfigurationFinder.FindMigrationsConfiguration(Type contextType, String configurationTypeName, Func`2 noType, Func`3 multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindConfiguration()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
```

So, what do you think about this exception? How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you see *System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unable to open configSource file 'bin\ConnectionStrings.config'.* - it seems you're referencing this config file, but it's not there.....

Comment: @marc_s Sorry, I editted the question

Comment: Please check the path of ConnectionStrings.config file

Comment: @Raghuveer I added many migrations before this exception, so there is no problem with path

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framework, The `type initializer error` is most likely due to malformed `Web.config` files, like having two or more sections of the connection string, or having problems in the connection string itself, such as invalid provider.
Instead of the below section in your `App.Config`

```
<connectionStrings configSource="bin\ConnectionStrings.config" />
```

try to locate below code directly in your `App.Config`.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Finance" connectionString="data source=192.168.0.6;initial catalog=Finance_Test;user id=sa;password=$Finance@92"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

good luck.

Comment: I can not use `connectionStrings` directly in this `App.Config` file because I have used it in multiple `App.config` files in entire solution. (ConnectionStrings.config file is **Single Source of Truth**)

Comment: Can you check your `bin` folder and make sure the `ConnectionStrings.config` is there or not ?!